# Profiling a Linq.DataContext without explicitly using GlimpseDbConnection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, glimpse

We're using LinqToSQL and Glimpse with the connection set up like below:

```
if (ApplicationSettings.ProfileDatabaseQueries)
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var conn = new GlimpseDbConnection(connection);
    context = new ApplicationDatabaseDataContext(conn, mappingSource);
}
else
{
    context = new ApplicationDatabaseDataContext(connectionString, mappingSource);
}
```

I read in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428196/remove-glimpsedbconnection-when-glimpse-is-disabled) that if you use DbProviderFactories then Glimpse hooks in automatically rather than us having to before the switch using a web.config key.

Does anyone have any sample code showing how to achieve this with a System.Data.Linq.DataContext?

As an aside do you need to explicitly add the provider in the connection string using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `DbProviderFactories` infrastructure instead of manually handelling things like you have in the above, it would look like the following:

Code:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MusicStoreEntities"];
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionString.ProviderName); 
context = new ApplicationDatabaseDataContext(factory.CreateConnection(), mappingSource);
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Other stuff -->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <!-- Other stuff -->
</configuration>
```

When you do the above, you won't need to have the `if (ApplicationSettings.ProfileDatabaseQueries)` check anymore. You could just turn Glimpse on and off in your web.config and not have to change any other code.

Note, you will want to use the connection string that L2S is used to using instead of the vanilla one I have here.

Comment: That worked perfectly; I used the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider and Glimpse has picked it up without the wrapper. Thank you Anthony